# How to setup HTTPS with Gunicorn on AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, openssl, gunicorn

I am currently trying to deploy a Flask API on an AWS EC2 instance. I use Gunicorn to launch the API and it worked well when binding it to port 5000. However, **I want to be able to secure the API with HTTPS protocole**. For this, I used self-signed certificate by following this [tutorial](https://devopscube.com/create-self-signed-certificates-openssl/) and then I changed `myapp.service` file to this :

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myapp
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ec2-user
Group=ec2-user
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/myapp
Environment="PATH=/home/ec2-user/myapp/env/bin"
Environment="FLASK_ENV=prod"
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/myapp/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:443 --keyfile /home/ec2-user/openssl/server.key --certfile /home/ec2-user/openssl/server.crt --ca-certs /home/ec2-user/openssl/rootCA.crt wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I added a rule to open port 443 on my EC2 instance.

However, when I launch Gunicorn with this configuration I get the following error :

```
(env) [ec2-user@<EC2 IP> openssl]$ sudo systemctl status myapp
× myapp.service - Gunicorn instance to serve myapp
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-07-05 07:05:17 UTC; 2s ago
   Duration: 5.165s
    Process: 274144 ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/myapp/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:443 --keyfile /home/ec2-user/openssl/server.key --certfile /home/ec2-user/openssl/server.crt --ca-certs /home/ec2-user/openssl/rootCA.crt wsg>
   Main PID: 274144 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 160ms

Started myapp.service - Gunicorn instance to serve myapp.
[INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 443)
myapp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
myapp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Could you help me with this ?

Comment: Did you configure your EC2 instance to run on the public subnet of your VPC? Does your security group expose HTTP and HTTPS ports directly to the public internet?

Comment: Yes it is situated in a public group. As I mentionnend I tried the API with the port 5000 and it was working. And yes I have the rules to expose HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, it seems that the Gunicorn process is unable to bind to port 443. Port numbers below 1024 are known as privileged ports and only root can bind to these ports by default. Here are some potential solutions to this problem:

### Run Gunicorn as Root:

While this can be an easy solution, it is generally not a recommended approach due to security reasons. Running your application as root would give it more privileges than it requires, potentially leaving your system vulnerable to attacks.

Use authbind:
Authbind is a tool that allows non-root users to bind to privileged ports. Install authbind, give the necessary permissions to the user, and modify the command that starts Gunicorn accordingly.

```bash
sudo yum install authbind
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/443
sudo chown ec2-user /etc/authbind/byport/443
sudo chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/443
```

Modify your myapp.service file to start gunicorn with authbind:

```bash
ExecStart=/usr/bin/authbind /home/ec2-user/myapp/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:443 --keyfile /home/ec2-user/openssl/server.key --certfile /home/ec2-user/openssl/server.crt --ca-certs /home/ec2-user/openssl/rootCA.crt wsgi:app
```

### Use a reverse proxy server:

You could use a reverse proxy server like Nginx or Apache to listen on port 443 and forward requests to your Flask application running on a non-privileged port. This is often considered the best practice because it provides a layer of abstraction and security to your Flask application.

Note that if you choose to use a reverse proxy, you won't need to provide the certificate and keyfile in your Gunicorn command, as the SSL termination would be done at the reverse proxy server.

Also, ensure that your self-signed certificates have been properly created and are in the right location. Check the certificate paths in the command to make sure they are correct.

Here's an example of how you might configure Nginx for this purpose:

Install Nginx if it's not already installed:

```bash
sudo yum install nginx
```

Create a new configuration file for your Flask application under `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` with the following content (Replace `6000` with the port on which your Gunicorn server is running):

```bash
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_server_domain_or_IP;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6000;
    }
}
```

Then you can configure SSL for Nginx:

```bash
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name your_server_domain_or_IP;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6000;
    }
}
```

You would need to replace `/etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt` and `/etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key` with the paths to your actual certificate files.

After these changes, you can test the Nginx configuration:

```bash
sudo nginx -t
```

If there are no syntax errors, you can restart Nginx to apply the changes:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart ngnix
```

This way, Nginx is serving as a reverse proxy, handling incoming traffic on ports 80 and 443 and forwarding it to your Gunicorn server. You're still securing your traffic with HTTPS, but you're avoiding the need for Gunicorn to bind to a low-numbered port, thus bypassing the permissions issue.

Remember to always test configuration changes in a controlled and secure environment before deploying them to production. It's always important to follow the principle of least privilege when setting up systems.

Try any of the 2 ways, but for security reasons I'll strongly recommend you use reverse proxy. Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).